# Ubuntu server does not display any webpage in browser

Tags: localhost, ubuntu-14.04

Initially I was installing wordpress on ubuntu, it does not display wordpress install page, so then I took it off of var/www/html and realize that ubuntu does not display any webpage including the index.html that was initially in var/www/html. it just displays a blank page.

I've looked at the host file, it is pointing to var/www/html. I've curled var/www/html, there is the html file there.

the access.log displays:

`127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2015:16:01:46 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11764 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2015:16:03:23 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11764 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2015:16:27:05 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11764 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2015:16:34:44 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11764 "-" "curl/7.35.0"`

the error.log file displays:

`[Tue Mar 10 17:30:54.378078 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1557:tid 140692943787904] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Mar 10 17:31:34.564745 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1557:tid 140692943787904] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 10 17:32:58.900759 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1178:tid 140402444928896] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 10 17:32:58.910206 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1178:tid 140402444928896] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Mar 10 17:34:57.716505 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1178:tid 140402444928896] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 10 17:34:58.788823 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1545:tid 140609166165888] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 10 17:34:58.788932 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1545:tid 140609166165888] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Mar 10 17:38:38.658636 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1545:tid 140609166165888] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 10 17:38:39.729666 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1656:tid 140483257968512] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 10 17:38:39.729781 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1656:tid 140483257968512] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`

Does anyone have any possible idea what is causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are the configs?

Answer (score 0):

Re-install Apache and PHP, Wordpress and any dependencies

- Make sure your host names are not conflicting
- Make sure your sites-available conf files are being loaded by Apache and are correct
  (I've heard that adding ".conf" to the end of the files helps Apache find them)
- Make sure Apache PID is in the right place / Apache knows where to find it
  (/var/run/apache2.pid)
- Ensure your not being DoS'ed by Anonymous ;)

Hope that helps